# Pandas DataFrame sort by categorical column but by specific class ordering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, categorical-data

I would like to select the top entries in a Pandas dataframe base on the entries of a specific column by using `df_selected = df_targets.head(N)`.

Each entry has a `target` value (by order of importance):

```
Likely Supporter, GOTV, Persuasion, Persuasion+GOTV
```

Unfortunately if I do

```
df_targets = df_targets.sort("target")
```

the ordering will be alphabetical (`GOTV`,`Likely Supporter`, ...).

I was hoping for a keyword like `list_ordering` as in:

```
my_list = ["Likely Supporter", "GOTV", "Persuasion", "Persuasion+GOTV"] 
df_targets = df_targets.sort("target", list_ordering=my_list)
```

To deal with this issue I create a dictionary:

```
dict_targets = OrderedDict()
dict_targets["Likely Supporter"] = "0 Likely Supporter"
dict_targets["GOTV"] = "1 GOTV"
dict_targets["Persuasion"] = "2 Persuasion"
dict_targets["Persuasion+GOTV"] = "3 Persuasion+GOTV"
```

, but it seems like a non-pythonic approach.

Suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: you mean `OrderedDict` right?

Comment: Read [this part](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#reordering) of the documentation.

Comment: Yes, `OrderedDict`

Answer (score 49):

I think you need [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html) with parameter `ordered=True` and then sorting by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) works very nice:

Check documentation for [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html):

> **Ordered Categoricals** can be sorted according to the custom order of the categories and can have a min and max value.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['GOTV', 'Persuasion', 'Likely Supporter', 
                         'GOTV', 'Persuasion', 'Persuasion+GOTV']})

df.a = pd.Categorical(df.a, 
                      categories=["Likely Supporter","GOTV","Persuasion","Persuasion+GOTV"],
                      ordered=True)

print (df)
                  a
0              GOTV
1        Persuasion
2  Likely Supporter
3              GOTV
4        Persuasion
5   Persuasion+GOTV

print (df.a)
0                GOTV
1          Persuasion
2    Likely Supporter
3                GOTV
4          Persuasion
5     Persuasion+GOTV
Name: a, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [Likely Supporter < GOTV < Persuasion < Persuasion+GOTV]
```

```
df.sort_values('a', inplace=True)
print (df)
                  a
2  Likely Supporter
0              GOTV
3              GOTV
1        Persuasion
4        Persuasion
5   Persuasion+GOTV
```

Comment: I think you need `Series`, if need indexes.[More info about Categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#object-creation).

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the most sufficient one, to prefer in case you face certain situation:
This is your preferred ordering...

```
my_order = ["Likely Supporter", "GOTV", "Persuasion", "Persuasion+GOTV"]
```

So, just do...

```
df['Column_to_update'].cat.reorder_categories(my_order, inplace= True)
```

It is flexible and no need to assign new category. But... **Your column must be `dtype = 'category'`** otherwise it will not work.

[Read more here (Pandas documentation)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html)

Comment: Pandas decided that they don't approve of this methodology. `The "inplace" parameter in pandas.Categorical.reorder_categories is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Reordering categories will always return a new Categorical object.`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jerzrael's input and references,

I like this sliced solution:

```
list_ordering = ["Likely Supporter","GOTV","Persuasion","Persuasion+GOTV"]  

df["target"] = df["target"].astype("category", categories=list_ordering, ordered=True)
```

Comment: you can edit your answer instead of posting another one