# How to take a log file that has all the data in rows and turn it into a column based output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Currently I have a log file that looks like this:

```
 PS       V       I       P
PSX1    1.802   .006    .011
PSX4    1.113   .179    .199
PSX2    1.111   .036    .041
PSX3    1.095   .003    .046

PSX1    1.802   .007    .014
PSX4    1.114   .180    .201
PSX2    1.111   .038    .041
PSX3    1.096   .003    .005
```

I wanted to change it to where it would look like this after passing through the script

```
   PSX1         PSX2         PSX3        PSX4
V   I   P    V   I   P    V   I   P    V   I   P
#   #   #    #   #   #    #   #   #    #   #   #
#   #   #    #   #   #    #   #   #    #   #   #
.   .   .    .   .   .    .   .   .    .   .   . 
.   .   .    .   .   .    .   .   .    .   .   .
```

I have been using pandas to mess with the data frames and I'm not exactly sure how to achieve this or if it is even possible to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `df.set_index('PS').T` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `cumcount` create the new index key , then we do `unstack` and adjust the columns level by using `swaplevel` + `sort_index`

```
df=df.assign(newindex=df.groupby('PS').cumcount())
df.set_index(['newindex','PS']).unstack().swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).sort_index(level=0,axis=1)
Out[91]: 
PS         PSX1                 PSX2                 PSX3                \
              I      P      V      I      P      V      I      P      V   
newindex                                                                  
0         0.006  0.011  1.802  0.036  0.041  1.111  0.003  0.046  1.095   
1         0.007  0.014  1.802  0.038  0.041  1.111  0.003  0.005  1.096   
PS         PSX4                
              I      P      V  
newindex                       
0         0.179  0.199  1.113  
1         0.180  0.201  1.114
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much! Is there a way to make it V I P instead of I P V? if there isn't that's not a big deal I'm just curious.

Comment: @MohitModi you can using category sort

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by category sort?

Comment: @MohitModi check the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223256/pandas-dataframe-sort-by-categorical-column-but-by-specific-class-ordering